# Login page with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I building an JQM app and im no shark in JQM just yet. the content of it is sensitive, 
so i would like to create a login page without having to contact serverside (MySql), 
is this even possible,
I have been fumbling around, with various answers that i have found here on StackOverflow,
but i just can´t seem to figure it out. The login page should just contain Username and password.
could anyone, please help me with this problem? 
maybe with the working code and maybe explain how to set it up.

Comment: Hey Bjarne. Welcome to SO..... this question is a bit too vague for us. SO isn't meant to be a design-providing or coding factory. Try something, start writing code, come back with an actual question, not for us to do the work for you.  Thanx :)

Comment: allright, i still stink it is relevant thoe, anyway it was worth a try

Comment: not saying it's not relevant... saying you should ask for SOMETHING more than "please provide me the code".... if you edit your question people will answer it